# C++ Pipe delimited text file to comma delimited

Tags: c++, xcode

How can you convert a pipe delimited text file into comma delimited? The pipe text file needs to be converted into comma delimited and stored in an output file.

For example if I had a pipe .txt file like this:

```
Available tickets|Seat numbers|Ticket Prices|Total Balance|Tax increase|Payment Method|Ticket Fees|Seats        
1234567|5778|Jonas, Jack|1652|5,873.90|Balance|230|3,567.98|Free soda refills       
1876543|2468|Johnson,George|9059|2,187.53|deposit|904|2,457.90|Price for street parking               
130240|3490|Angel, Mike|4237|1,045.50|Balance|560|3,509.87| Ending Balance
```

Comment: Is reading the input file and writing the output file, character by character, and converting pipes to comma characters, too obvious?

Comment: It is not that easy because the file already has commas so it gets complex because I believe that quotes need to be added in some areas as well @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: Ok, so add the quotes, then. The logic is still fairly simple, and this can still be done, character by character. Or, if you prefer, `std::getline` each line, one line at a time, split the `std::string` containing a single line by the "`|`" characters, then output each field, with surrounding quotes, and with "`,`" as separators. Mission accomplished, wasn't that easy?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add quotes only where needed, you can store each section between pipes in a temporary string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream input;
    input.open("theFile");

    ofstream output;
    input.open("otherFile");

    string temp;
    while (getline(input, temp, '|')) {
        if (temp.find(",") != string::npos)
            output << '"' << temp << "\",";
        else
            output << temp << ',';
    }
}
```